# Xpath find div with no divs with same text

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Have structure like this:

```
<div> **the div I dont need**
    <div> **the div I need**
        <div>first part of text</div>
        <div>second part of text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need div, which contains both parts of text, but only last such div.
I don't know which text it will be on the stage of getting element, and I dont know, how much of these elements will be on page.
When I try

> By.XPath(".//div[normalize-space(.) and count(div[normalize-space(.)])
>   = 0]")

It gives me 2 divs with different parts of text.

So question is, how to have it return div, which have no lesser divs with same text, when there is no predefined text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the parent element with `parent::` or `..`

```
By.XPath(".//div[normalize-space(.) and count(div[normalize-space(.)]) = 0]/parent::div")
```

Or

```
By.XPath(".//div[normalize-space(.) and count(div[normalize-space(.)]) = 0]/..")
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice one